# Different date formats in one column R

Tags: r, date

I have a column with different date formats:

I tried to solve this with anytime function but I get NA for the second format.

```
library(anytime)

dates <- c("2017-01-23 00:00:00.000",
           "2017-1-23 00:00:00.000",
           "20.02.2017 11:15",
           "2.2.2017 11:15")

anytime(dates)

[1] "2017-01-23 CET" "2017-01-23 CET" NA               NA
```

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: It would help to understand the full range of potential date formats. I don't think there's a magic bullet, rather you would set up a few tests to diagnose which format to use, and then apply it. For instance, `library(tidyverse); library(lubridate); dates %>% mutate(dates = case_when(date %>% str_detect(".201") ~ mdy_hm(dates), TRUE ~ ymd_hms(dates))`

Comment: There those formats only. I tried your code it is not working.

Comment: Is the fourth one day-month-year or month-day-year? I'll assume day-month-yr like the 3rd row...

Comment: Yes it is like a 3rd row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit -- I had a typo in using `dmy_hms` where it should have been `dmy_hm`.

This approach relies on there being a clue in the string as to which format to use. Here I assume all the dates are between 2010 and the end of 2019, and that the day-month-year strings all use a dot between the parts of the date.

```
library(tidyverse); library(lubridate); 
dates %>% 
  enframe() %>%
  # Edit -- better solution
  mutate(dates = case_when(value %>% str_detect("\\d{4}\\-") ~ ymd_hms(dates), 
                       TRUE ~ dmy_hm(dates)))
# A tibble: 4 x 3
   name value                   dates              
  <int> <chr>                   <dttm>             
1     1 2017-01-23 00:00:00.000 2017-01-23 00:00:00
2     2 2017-1-23 00:00:00.000  2017-01-23 00:00:00
3     3 20.02.2017 11:15        2017-02-20 11:15:00
4     4 2.2.2017 11:15          2017-02-02 11:15:00


  # old solution
  mutate(dates = case_when(value %>% str_detect(".201") ~ dmy_hm(dates), 
                           TRUE ~ ymd_hms(dates)))
```

Comment: But the 3rd and 4th dates are wrong? It should be 2017 and converted dates are 2020?

Comment: Would be great to find some universal solution which would also cover years over and under that range. But thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Edited to be less hacky. Now looks for four digits followed by a dash, which should be "unversal" provided all your data is just those two formats.